# Get Bitcoin Gold from paper wallet

Tags: bitcoin-gold

Now that bitcoin gold launched, I am looking for a way to get my BTG from the BTC paper wallet they were held at the forked block.

I know Coinomi works, but it only has an android app... any other that has a web or desktop app?

Comment: I'm asking specifically for non-android (Coinomi) which hasn't been answered.

Comment: If you go to https://bitcoingold.org/downloads/ you can see a variety of wallets that support BTG. HOWEVER I only deem Trezor, Ledger and Coinomi as trustworthy. If you want to take the risk, go on and try the other wallets.

Comment: That question is not android-specific, so I think it covers this question too. I think it's better to keep all the responses in the same place. If you find a good solution, why don't to reply to the other question? ;-)

Comment: brec's answer below is a good solution. I'm letting him copy it to the other question to take the credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Coinomi through the Google Chrome browser. You install the ARC Welder extension...
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn

...which lets you run Android apps without an Android device. Download the required .apk (the wallet app) from https://coinomi.com/downloads .

Edit: I discovered this on this reddit thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinAirdrops/comments/7hc0qu/best_way_to_claim_bcash_from_old_core_walletdat/

which also has some possibly helpful tips.